# Spring DI and creating objects

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I want to create an object only if it does not exist on the database.
In plain java i would do something like

```
MyObject getObject(String id) {
       MyObject myObject = myDao.getById(id);
       if(myObject == null) {
           myObject = new MyObject("Some Parameter");
       }
       return myObject;
}
```

I now want to use Spring for this. 
My idea is using a Factory that is injected beforehand.
Something in the direction of (but with constructor injection):

```
@Autowired
MyObjectFactory myObjectFactory;

MyObject getObject(String id) {
       MyObject myObject = myDao.getById(id);
       if(myObject == null) {
           myObject = myObjectFactory.newInstance("Some Parameter");
       }
       return myObject;
}
```

But to be sure I wanted to ask what options there are and which method is preferred going in line with Springs DI.

*** EDIT 1 ***
Fixed Autowired annotation

*** EDIT 2 ***
Copyinf from one of my comments

I have to have a bit more logic in the getObject method than shown here.

I have to check for different unique keys to find a matching object, and only if I find no object with the different approaches, then I will create a new one. I just kept the code small for the question. 
This is why I would rather not use the create if not found approach.

Also I try to keep the code testable and abstract the object creation from the method.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the idea, but Spring's annotation for dependency injection is `@Autowired` and not `@Autoinject`.

Comment: Wouldnt an Id mean the object already exists in DB?

Comment: @Jesper right thanks, fixed it. Not thinking about solutions while writing demo code for questions on SO would help ;)

Comment: @farrellmr yes, but i get the id from file, so it might not exist. Also this is just a small version of the problem. Actually i need to check a few more cases of getting the MyObject object from DB before creating a new one.

Comment: Objects queried from a database are generally not Spring beans, so it might be fine to create them with `new`. What are you exact requirements?

Comment: @SergeBallesta i edited the question. 1. the conditions here are simplified. 2. The idea is to keep the code testable, which is easier if you don't call new in the code itself, since a method call can be mocked and tested if it was called.

Answer (score 0):

"I want to create an object only if it does not exist on the `database`."

I think you can use repository to check if there is `object` with that `id`
if not - then create it.

To use `repository` use e.g:

```
 @Autowired
 private PersonRepository repository;
```

then check if element exists use:

```
repository.findOne(id);
```

Is something wrong with that approach?

`Spring repository:`

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html

Comment: This approach is a valid one, and I already use it similarly, but i have to have a bit more logic in the getObject method than shown here. I have to check for different unique keys to find a matching object, and only if i find none with the different approaches then i will create a new one. I just kept the code small for the question. This is why i would rather not use the create if not found approach.